# conditional rendering styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, oop, ecmascript-6, styled-components

Been struggling with this for a while now, I'm trying to change the color of my text based on the value selected from my dropdown component

```
const DropdownSelectPriority = props => {
  const { multiChoiceArray } = props
  return (
    <ButtonContainer>
      {multiChoiceArray.map(questionChoice => {
        return (
          <Item key={questionChoice.id}>
            <p>{questionChoice.text}</p>
            <SimpleSelect
              placeholder="Select a priority"
              onValueChange={value => console.log(value)}
            >
              {questionChoice.options.map(options => {
                return <option value={options.label}>{options.value}</option>
              })}
            </SimpleSelect>
          </Item>
        )
      })}
    </ButtonContainer>
  )
}

const Item = styled.div`
  .react-selectize {
    color: ${props => {
      const value = props.options && props.options.value
      if (value === 'My highest priority') {
        return 'green'
      }
      return 'blue'
    }};
  }
`
```

options array

```
  options: [
          {
            id: 1,
            label: 'Greenhouse gas reduction',
            value: 'Not a priority for me',
            priority: '',
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            label: 'Greenhouse gas reduction',
            value: 'Somewhere in the middle',
            priority: '',
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            label: 'Greenhouse gas reduction',
            value: 'My highest priority',
            priority: '',
          },
        ],
```

Right now, it's rendering all values as blue, which means my specific condition is not being met...Where am I going wrong? `{options.value}` is where I am trying to apply the style

Comment: where are you actually changing the value? Does that happen inside SimpleSelect` somehow? Also, you shouldn't change props values from within the component. Use state instead.

Comment: my value is being changed  in my <SimpleSelect component \>`onValueChange={value => console.log(value)}` , I'm not familiar with react-hooks just yet so i'm using a functional component

Comment: that code doesn't change the value of `options.value`

Comment: @ChristianFritz Hmm, I'm not sure then, that's the only event listener...Here's the docs for the library